# Scrapy: Fetching the content set via Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl [this](http://www.bedstore.co.uk/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm) URL. It changes cost from 130 ot 154.99 via Javascript. When you see view source of Price DOM it looks like:

```
<span id="item_price_6516">&pound;130.00</span>
```

And it's definitely setting via JavaScript.

How can I fetch the correct value via scrapy?

The way I tried to fetch value is:

```
price = hxs.select('//*[@id="display_price"]/span[2]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is *constructed with the help of javascript being executed when you load the page in the browser*. The desired price is actually inside one the `script` tags which you can locate with Scrapy, extract the object containing price with regular expressions, load it via JSON and get the price.

Demo from the [`Scrapy Shell`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.bedstore.co.uk/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm
In [1]: import re 
In [2]: import json
In [3]: pattern = re.compile(r"qubit_product_list = (.*?);", re.M)
In [4]: script = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'qubit_product_list')]/text()").extract()[0]
In [5]: data = pattern.search(script).group(1)
In [6]: json.loads(data)
Out[6]: 
{u'6516-DBL-BLK': {u'category': u'',
  u'currency': u'GBP',
  u'description': u'Double Black',
  u'id': u'6516',
  u'name': u'Diamante Faux Leather Bed Frame',
  u'sku_code': u'LPDF:DIAMANTE-BD',
  u'stock': 100,
  u'unit_price': 129.99,
  u'unit_sale_price': 129.99,
  u'url': u'/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm'},
 u'6516-DBL-WHT': {u'category': u'',
  u'currency': u'GBP',
  u'description': u'Double White',
  u'id': u'6516',
  u'name': u'Diamante Faux Leather Bed Frame',
  u'sku_code': u'LPDF:DIAMANTE-WD',
  u'stock': 100,
  u'unit_price': 129.99,
  u'unit_sale_price': 129.99,
  u'url': u'/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm'},
 u'6516-KS-BLK': {u'category': u'',
  u'currency': u'GBP',
  u'description': u'Kingsize Black',
  u'id': u'6516',
  u'name': u'Diamante Faux Leather Bed Frame',
  u'sku_code': u'LPDF:DIAMANTE-BK',
  u'stock': 99,
  u'unit_price': 149.99004,
  u'unit_sale_price': 149.99004,
  u'url': u'/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm'},
 u'6516-KS-WHT': {u'category': u'',
  u'currency': u'GBP',
  u'description': u'Kingsize White',
  u'id': u'6516',
  u'name': u'Diamante Faux Leather Bed Frame',
  u'sku_code': u'LPDF:DIAMANTE-WK',
  u'stock': 100,
  u'unit_price': 154.98996,
  u'unit_sale_price': 154.98996,
  u'url': u'/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm'}}
```

Comment: `data = pattern.search(script).group(1)` gives error: *TypeError: expected string or buffer*

Comment: @Volatil3 interesting, no error on my side. Using python 2.7.9 and scrapy 0.24.5. What is the value of `script` you see? Thanks.

Comment: Guess it's OSX thing. Let me try within script

Comment: Weird it parse object to dict in shell but not within script via Loader. I find nothing as output

Comment: @Volatil3 please see if there is more sense to create a new question in case of difficulties applying the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642362/scrapy-cant-convert-json-string-to-dict-object

Comment: for some URLS like this(view-source:http://www.bedstore.co.uk/p/Orlando_Low_Foot_End_Bed_Frame.htm) it's not letting to parse JSON and giving error: *Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 2159 (char 2158)*. I thought it's due to new line character so replaced `\n` but it's still saying same. It tried to parse this structure: http://pastebin.com/AAn0ATAC Can you look at it please? I guess it's RegEx Issue

Comment: Infact you just apply your code for given URL you will see it did not extract entire JSON structure.

Comment: @Volatil3 I think you need to change your regular expression to `qubit_product_list = (.*?);\n`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fetch the correct value via scrapy?

Scrapy's downloader is not a browser and doesn't execute javascript. But you could:

1.Inspect what is going on with Firebug or Chrome Console and construct you request to AJAX api manually just yielding it e.g.:

```
def parse_my_ajax_page(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(url, ..., callback=self.parse_my_ajax_request)
```

or extract desired data from script tag as proposed above by alecxe (if it's present).

2.Use javascript rendering service like [Prerender](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) or [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) (from Scrapy creators).

3.Use Selenium or PhantomJS directly (very slow and buggy).

Comment: No AJAX thing going on.