# Unable to convert returned JSON data into Dict in Scrapy

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I am using `scrapy` to get a certain piece of data from [here](http://www.bedstore.co.uk/p/Diamante_Faux_Leather_Bed_Frame.htm). As I was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565102/scrapy-fetching-the-content-set-via-javascript/29593152#29593152), I used the following code in my script:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"qubit_product_list = (.*?);", re.M)
        script = hxs.select("//script[contains(., 'qubit_product_list')]/text()").extract()[0]
        data = pattern.search(script).group(1)

        j_data = json.loads(data)
        self.log('After calling LOAD Begins')
        self.log(j_data) #It is not printing ANYTHING!!!!
        self.log('After calling LOAD Ends')

        self.log('\n---------------------------------\n')
```

Which outputs following from variable `data`:

```
{
    "9102-DBL-sprung slat base": {
        "id": "9102",
        "name": "Imperial Bedstead",
        "url": "/p/Imperial_Bedstead.htm",
        "description": "Double - Sprung Slat Base",
        "unit_price": 429.99,
        "unit_sale_price": 429.99,
        "currency": "GBP",
        "sku_code": "BENT:1320B-Beech",
        "category": "Bed Frames",
        "stock": 100
    },
    "9102-KS-sprung slat base": {
        "id": "9102",
        "name": "Imperial Bedstead",
        "url": "/p/Imperial_Bedstead.htm",
        "description": "Kingsize - Sprung Slat Base",
        "unit_price": 439.98996,
        "unit_sale_price": 439.98996,
        "currency": "GBP",
        "sku_code": "BENT:1326B-Beech",
        "category": "Bed Frames",
        "stock": 100
    }
}
```

Now, I want to convert this `json` like structure to python `dict`. I tried following but it returns `unicode` type.

```
j_data = json.loads(data)
```

So, how do I get Array/Dict in Python 2.7? Ironically same `loads` method is returning of type `dict` when using `scrapy shell`.

Comment: Using `json.loads` under Python 2.7 works without any problems.

Comment: Isn't this already a python dictionary? A nested one although. Your data variable is already of type dict.

Comment: @Siddhant It appeaars as `dict`. The same thing shows of type `dict` when using on console but when running via Python Server it is treating as string.

Comment: @Siddhant As can be seen from the code, `data` is the result of a regular expression. It is a string, not a dictionary. It must be parsed.

Comment: @Tichodroma and what should be of return type of data from `json.loads`?

Comment: @Volatil3 The return type will be `dict` for your `data`.

Comment: @Tichodroma That's what I thought. As you said `json.loads` method works perfectly on the given input returning a `dict`

Comment: @Tichodroma When I use iteration then instead of returning keys it returns one by one character.

Comment: @Volatil3 Iteration on what? How?

Comment: @Tichodroma on data return from `json.loads(data)`

Comment: No. Iteration `for k in json.loads(data)` iterates over the keys of the parse `dict`. Please edit your question and include all code you try.

Comment: @Volatil3 - Since you said it is showing data variable as type `dict` in console. Try converting the above to type `str` by `data = str(data)` and then use the `json.loads` method on data.

Comment: @Volatil3 try `self.log(str(j_data))`

Comment: @Siddhant printing nothing, empty!

Comment: @Siddhant I had done double typecasting. I removed `data = str(data)` and now it prints `{u'7073': {u'category': u'Willis and Gambier', u'unit_sale_price': 454.98996, u'description': u'', u'url': u'/p/Steens_Whitewash_Bunk_Bed_Frame.htm', u'sku_code': u'STEN:29061513', u'unit_price': 454.98996, u'currency': u'GBP', u'stock': 100, u'id': u'7073', u'name': u'Steens Whitewash Bunk Bed Frame'}}`

Comment: Great. That is what I suspected. Please upvote the comment where I suggested the same. :)

Comment: @Siddhant So is it already dict now?

Comment: @Volatil3 Yes. It's a `dict` now. As is evident from your previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#typecasting the JSON to string for json.loads to work
data = str(data)
#returning type dict from json
j_data = json.loads(data)
#typecasting the dict to string before writing to log
self.log(str(j_data))
```